# How to use xpath to get text from similar class?

Tags: python, html, xpath

(1)

```
</div>
        <div class="n_cont5" id="nct7">
            <div class="nc_tit">说明书：</div>
            <div class="nc5" id="smsdiv">
                正在查询请稍候......
            </div>
        </div>




        <div class="n_page"><a href="javascript:MoveTo(-1);">上一篇</a>第<span class="cur">2</span>篇<a href="javascript:MoveTo(+1);">下一篇</a>共<span>53</span>篇<a href="javascript:changeTo();">转到</a>第
            <input type="text" name="pages" id="pages"
                    onkeydown="return SubmitKeyClick(this,event)"
                    onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'')"
                    onbeforepaste="clipboardData.setData('text',clipboardData.getData('text').replace(/[^\d]/g,''))"/>
            篇</div>

    </div>
```

(2)

```
                                    <a href="javascript:noAction()" title="PDF下载"
                                    onclick="pdfDownloadDetail('Unexamined_patent_for_invention/2016/20160330/CN105452223A/PDF_PID/CN112014000037041CN00001054522230APDFZH20160330CN00F.PDF,CN201480037041.6')" href="javascript:noAction()">PDF下载</a>
                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:noAction();" onclick="window.print();" class="icon6">打印</a></li>
                    <li><a class="icon7" href="javascript:noAction();" class="zidongfanyi"
                        onclick="translateToEn('CN201480037041.6', 'FMZL_EN,SYXX_EN')">中译英</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="n_page"><a href="javascript:MoveTo(-1);">上一篇</a>第<span class="cur">2</span>篇<a href="javascript:MoveTo(+1);">下一篇</a>共<span>53</span>篇<a href="javascript:changeTo();">转到</a>第
            <input type="text" name="pages" id="pages"
                    onkeydown="return SubmitKeyClick(this,event)"
                    onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'')"
                    onbeforepaste="clipboardData.setData('text',clipboardData.getData('text').replace(/[^\d]/g,''))"/>
            篇</div>
```

Here are two very similar content in the html content. Iwant to get the number "53" from the first?. I used the below code which doesn't work. I also try from div class, but it also failed.  How can I get the number "53" from the first html content?

```
  html.xpath('//a[contains(text(),"下一篇")]/span/text()')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it didn't work : the span holding `53` is a sibling (not a child) of the `a` element.

To complete @super.single430's answer, here's an alternative (if encoding issues occur during the parsing process) :

```
//span[@class="cur"]/following-sibling::span/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'下一篇')]/following-sibling::span/text()")
```